ElevatedButtonThemeData class in ElevatedButton in Flutter
I have created a separate theme class to design my text style, button styling, etc. In my theme class, I am using ElevatedButtonThemeData. I have created the style.ElevatedButton.style from but my text styling not working on the text.
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: context.percentHeight * 8,
      width: context.percentWidth * 76,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        style: AppTheme().themeData.elevatedButtonTheme.style,
        child: Text(
          text,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

   elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        elevation: 5,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.primary,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          color: AppColors.primary,
          fontSize: 20,
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans-SemiBold',
        ),
      )));

